# try_files like behavior on Google Load Balancer -> is it possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, load-balancing

I am trying to setup a Google Load Balancer in front of Google Storage Bucket (that part works), but I need a bit of extra functionality, I need something like try_files in NGINX, so rather than sending 404 back I want to try some other file (ideally something that came as http param), what I have in mind:
example request:
http:///?file1=example1.html&file2=example2.html
Then I'd like it to serve example1.html if it exists, and if not then example2.html.

I have freedom in terms of bucket structure as well as request, so for example a following request would also be ok:

http:///example2/example1
or any combination of URLs, parameters or headers

Also, in AWS this seems to be possible with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html#advanced-conditional-redirects but in GCP I haven't found solution on LB nor bucket side. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

For funcionality like that, I'd think that some form of serverless should be used alongside storage and the LB.

You could have like:

Request -> LB -> cloud Funcion (check if html1 exists, and if so, -> get the html1 from GCS; otherwise -> html2)

Please take a look at this documenation [1], You can invoke Cloud Functions with an HTTP request using the POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, and OPTIONS HTTP methods. Also check the Google Cloud Storage Triggers [2].

Regards.

Pablo.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http
[2] https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage

Comment: That I have already - but was hoping to skip cloud function in this setup - that would make it much simpler.